# date.toUTCString() it's not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, formatting

Hello when i try to convert my date to format UTC it throwing TypeError: date.toUTCString it's not a function any suggestions?

[image: Code]

Comment: Please add your code to the post, as text.

Comment: `Date.now()` does not returns a `Date` object.

Comment: Just fix it:                                                                                          
let date = new Date(Date.now());
let fixedDateFormat = date.toUTCString();

Answer (score 7):

As DontVoteMeDown said: Date.now() does not return a date object, instead Date.now() returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

To get the current timestamp as a Date object

```
var date = new Date( Date.now() );
```

Or more simply (but less readable)

```
var date = new Date();
```

Comment: I can't see how `new Date()` is less readable than `new Date()Date.now())`, in which the *Date.now* call is entirely redundant.

Comment: @RobG there's no way to know that `new Date()` constructs a date object for the current time without having read the documentation, or guessing. New Date could construct an empty Date object

Comment: There are many ways to obtain knowledge. The same logic could be applied to not knowing what *Date.now()* produces. You might even say `new Date(Date())` is more readable, since `Date()` returns a human readable string that is easily understood rather than the seemingly meaningless number returned by `Date.now()`.